# How to update Json data type in MySql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, json

I have column in my table that is Json data type.
In this column I record Phones data like this:

`{"0": "044-33565388", "1": "044-33565399", "2": "044-33565311"}`

For store data like this form, I use `textarea` and enter each phone number in a new line. Next pass data to php document that parse data something like this:

```
$phoneList = json_encode( explode("\r\n", $input), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

And insert data in mysql. Now I want to update or remove some `JSON` data. I try something like this but got error:

**Query:**

```
UPDATE `sellers` SET `seller_phone` = JSON_SET(`seller_phone`, {"0":"33565388","1":"33565399"}) WHERE `seller_id` = 8
```

**Error:**

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"0":"33565388","1":"33565399","2":"33565311"}) WHERE seller_id = 8' at line 1*

MySql version: 5.7.9

Now, What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `""` is it typo here `"33565399""}` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use JSON_SET for update and JSON_REMOVE for unset key.

use below query to update -

```
UPDATE `sellers` SET `seller_phone` = JSON_SET(`seller_phone`, "$.0", "33565388", "$.1", "33565399") WHERE `seller_id` = 8;
```

then run below to unset last key -

```
UPDATE `sellers`
SET `seller_phone` = JSON_REMOVE(`seller_phone`, "$.2") WHERE `seller_id` = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to understand the format for **JSON_SET**

> JSON_SET(column_name, path, val[, path, val]...)

To set values

```
JSON_SET(`seller_phone`, "$.0", "33565388", "$.1", "33565399")
```

So your Query will be:

```
UPDATE `sellers`
SET `seller_phone` = JSON_SET(`seller_phone`, "$.0", "33565388", "$.1", "33565399")
WHERE `seller_id` = 8
```

Comment: Thanks, the record updated, but I have another problem. last update of record is `{"0": "33565388", "1": "33565399", "2": "044-33565311"}`. I want to remove object 2. how can I do that?

Comment: you need to check how yo use JSON_REMOVE

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. **$Query:** `'UPDATE sellers SET  seller_phone = "[]" WHERE seller_id = '.$seller_id;`
2. **$Query:** `'UPDATE sellers SET  seller_phone = JSON_SET(seller_phone, '.$seller_phones.') WHERE seller_id = '.$seller_id;`

**Note:**

```
function explode_lines($seller_phones_input) {
    return explode("\r\n", $seller_phones_input);
}

function array_to_query($seller_phones) {

    $query = null;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($seller_phones); $i++){

        if ($i!=0){
            $query .= ", ";
        }

        $query .= '"$['.$i.']", "' . $seller_phones[$i] . '"';
    }

    return $query;
}
```